# How to maintain the order of the variables according to the third factor variable in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

In this data consider `c` and `t` as factors and `f` as frequency of `c`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(~"c", ~"f", ~"t",
              "a", 49, "zoo",
              "b", 12, "foo",
              "p", 9, "zoo",
              "q", 29, "foo",
              "c", 15, "zoo")
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(c), f, fill = t)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  aes(x = fct_reorder(c, f, .desc = F)) +
  coord_flip()
```

Above codes produce this plot

[image]

In the this plot how to keep similar variables together, like blue next to blue and red with red.

Answer (score 3):

We can split with `facet_grid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
     ggplot(aes(c, f, fill = t)) +
           geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
           aes(x = fct_reorder(c, f, .desc = F)) +
           coord_flip() + 
           facet_grid(~ t)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the outcome is not pretty due to empty rows in plot.

Comment: @AjayKumarKoli It is more easier to understand the plot.  But, if you go by the way you wanted, with more groups, it becomes difficult to gather insights

Comment: @dc37 your reply is perfect for the plot I was looking for. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to @akrun's answer, you can pass few arguments into `facet_grid` and `theme` function in order to make your faceted plot looks like a single one:

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(c), f, fill = t)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  aes(x = fct_reorder(c, f, .desc = F)) +
  coord_flip()+
  facet_grid(t~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")+
  theme(strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.margin.y = unit(-0.25, "lines"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We'll not need `facet_grid` if we `arrange` the data appropriately.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  arrange(t, f) %>%
  mutate(c = factor(c, levels = unique(c))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(c, f, fill = t)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]